# Why does my hostname resolve to IP of virtual nic and not the physical one?

Tags: networking, windows-8, virtualbox, dns

I've got Virtual Box installed in my Windows 8 computer, and as such I have a few virtual network adapters

My problem is that when I do `ping sedtdev1510` or programatically resolve the IP , from the local computer the IP of one of the virtual network adapters is returned instead of the IP of the physical adapter.

Example:

```
ping -4 sedtdev1510

Pinging SEDTDEV1510.euse.local [192.168.56.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.56.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

Expected IP is 172.16.5.126

- There are no entries in my "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" file.
- My physical network adapter is first in the "connections" list in "Advanced settings" for Network Connections.
- If I disable the virtual adapters, the correct IP is returned (not a long-term solution).
- If I ping my host name from another computer from the 172.16.5-net the correct IP is resolved so this is a local problem.

The DNS seems to be OK, as nslookup returns the correct IP:

```
nslookup sedtdev1510
Server:  ad01.euse.local
Address:  172.16.1.1

Name:    sedtdev1510.euse.local
Address:  172.16.5.126
```

So my question is, why does Windows behave this way and what do I need to do to get my host name to locally resolve to the IP from the physical adapter?

This is the output from ipconfig /all

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : SEDTDEV1510
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : euse.local
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : euse.local

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : euse.local
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 98-90-96-B4-66-E1
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::fd26:be25:db3b:6838%3(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.5.126(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : den 15 december 2015 14:14:24
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : den 16 december 2015 15:07:45
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 60330134
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-9C-48-85-98-90-96-B4-66-E1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.1.1
                                       172.16.1.2
                                       8.8.8.8
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-01
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2854:e80e:b60b:416f%5(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.146.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 134238294
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-9C-48-85-98-90-96-B4-66-E1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-08
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::14a6:6a9e:ed93:df80%7(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.147.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 167792726
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-9C-48-85-98-90-96-B4-66-E1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0A-00-27-00-00-00
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e552:b8e2:3ff1:32d4%9(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 201981991
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-9C-48-85-98-90-96-B4-66-E1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{51CFEB66-3366-4CA4-8423-EDB63EFBCB68}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{FA326420-7A0D-4FA4-A1C1-75293D8D172A}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{31E7A592-72C8-4AAF-8B5E-9032E0D73A1F}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : euse.local
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{9E609FF1-63E3-4C97-BE96-EFE454AE4065}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: TBH it's not very clear to me 1) where do you execute the `ping myHostName` which provides a "wrong" IP address, 2) is `myHostName` the host or the guest, 3) which of the `hosts` files are empty, 4) where are the other computers located which show the correct IP address (same LAN subnet, elsewhere). -- Obviously, since this is a DNS topic, it would certainly also help if you clarified the DNS setup you have and if Virtualbox offers various routing options for guests, then those could be relevant too (they would be if you used VMWare, I'm not familiar with exact Virtualbox options).

Comment: Updated with more info.

Comment: You seem to have a mixed `VMWare` and `Virtualbox` setup, interesting. Either way, you're using [`Virtualbox Host-Only` networking, which introduces an additional virtual network card for your host](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly), which is not visible to the outside -- but Windows can't know this. I guess once Windows figures that you ping your own computer, it juist uses one of the IP addresses which are known for it, not caring which one. Because it doesn't make a difference. No package will ever be sent to any wire; they're all handled internally in this case.

Comment: Yeah, that VMWare adapter is a leftover of a removed VMWare installation, it just won't go away. FYI, my computer at home has the same behavior - the IP of the VMWare adapter is returned (no VMWare adapters so they are not to blame). No packets on any wire makes perfect sense.

Comment: Try disabling Netbios within the VM

Comment: The VMs are not even started, but thanks for the idea.